# What does ProgrammingError at /contact/ mean?

Tags: python, django

I just added a contact form to my app then it returned this when I submitted the form. I don't have `blog_quotes` on my code and when I made migrations, nothing has changed.

```
ProgrammingError at /contact/
relation "blog_quotes" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "blog_quotes" ("name", "email", "description") V...
                ^
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://myapp.herokuapp.com/contact/
Django Version: 2.1.9
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "blog_quotes" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "blog_quotes" ("name", "email", "description") V...
                ^
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 85
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 16 Jun 2019 23:57:25 +0800
```

Here's my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Contact

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = [
            'name', 'email', 'description',
        ]
```

My models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "contact"
        verbose_name_plural = "contacts"
```

What did I miss?

Comment: We'd probably need more info. What does your form look like? Is it a ModelForm? What does the Model look like, if so?

Comment: You did not properly `makemigrations` and `migrate` your database.

Comment: Your SQL has an error.  Show us the full SQL statement from the code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did migrate properly on the heroku bash.

Comment: @Highcenburg: well the error says: `relation "blog_quotes" does not exist`, so that means the table to which Django queries does not exist.

Comment: Did you already do a project-wide search for `blog_quotes`? It's likely that you've copied code from another place and forgot to edit something out.

Comment: @LucaBezerra copied it from one of my old projects and I did change it already.

Comment: Did you also change database information (name, URL, whatnot)? If this is a starting project, you could try resetting all of your migrations to `zero`, deleting your migration files, recreating and re-running them.

Comment: @LucaBezerra That's it! I think I changed a name on this before migrating. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear! I've posted it as an answer so you can close the question as solved, if you feel like it :) Cheers!

Comment: @LucaBezerra I got curious what was happening under the hood so I ran inspectdb and got this class BlogContact(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'blog_contact'

Comment: It's unclear to me, was it something you created at some point?

Comment: @LucaBezerra Yes but I forgot what I created. How can I see what I've created under the hood?

Comment: When you say under the hood, what exactly do you mean? Stuff you've created directly via SQL or stuff created via the Django ORM? Your source of truth should always be your migrations and models. If the database is inconsistent with regards to these files, the best solution is to restart it from scratch. Obviously you can't do that when you already have lots of data, so ideally you'll never manually fiddle with migrations (unless you know exactly what and why you're doing) and you'll leave Django do its thing automatically.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It's stuff that I've created in the Django ORM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is a starting project, you could try resetting all of your migrations to zero, deleting your migration files, recreating and re-running them.